# javax.servlet.http.Cookie vs javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie

Tags: cookies

Being new to web development, I need some help in understanding what is the difference between the javax.servlet.http.Cookie and javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie.I assume that the latter can be used to set cookie into the response of a rest service. But can we also set the initial Cookie object into the HTTPServletResponse?

Answer (score 0):

These are objects that represent the same underlying entity, namely an HTTP cookie as defined by the RFC. Both "do" the same thing, representing a cookie header in an HTTP response (a request cookie is a name=value pair only, whereas response cookies can have several additional attributes as described in the RFC). Where you use one vs the other is simply a matter of what you are coding. If you are writing a JAX-RS provider, then the JAX-RS apis will use javax.ws.core.Cookie. If you are writing an HttpServlet, then you use the javax.servlet.http.Cookie. JAX-RS implementations will also allow you to use context injection so that you can have direct access to the HttpServlet objects within your JAX-RS service provider

Answer (score -1):

[javax.servlet.http.Cookie](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) is created and placed on the HTTP response object with the [addCookie](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie(javax.servlet.http.Cookie)) method.

Instead, the description for [javax.ws.core.Cookie](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Cookie.html) reads:

> Represents the value of a HTTP cookie, transferred in a request

… so you'd expect the [getCookies](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()) method on the HTTP request object to return an array of that type of cookies, but no, it returns an array of [javax.servlet.http.Cookie](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html). Apparently [javax.ws.core.Cookie](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Cookie.html) is used by some [methods in the javax.ws.rs packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/class-use/Cookie.html). So you use [javax.ws.core.Cookie](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Cookie.html) with jax-rs web services and [javax.servlet.http.Cookie](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) with HttpServlets and their request / response objects.